# Create a custom AsyncSequence

Tags: json, swift, async-await, swiftui

*NOTE: Currently config: Xcode 13 beta 3 (13A5192i), macOS Montery (21A5284e).*

Trying to asynchronously initialize data from a `json`.
The code apparently works fine, but the elements are not added to `@Published public private (set) var users = [User]()`

Is it something stupid I don't see or is it just another bug?

```json
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name":"gio"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name":"mimi"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name":"pepo"
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "name":"bassix"
    },
    {
        "id": 5,
        "name":"peponews"
    }
]
```

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct URLWatcher: AsyncSequence, AsyncIteratorProtocol {
    typealias Element = Data

    let url: URL
    let delay: Int
    private var comparisonData: Data?

    init(url: URL, delay: Int = 10) {
        self.url = url
        self.delay = delay
    }

    mutating func next() async throws -> Data? {

        if comparisonData == nil {
            comparisonData = try await fetchData()
        } else {
            while true {
                await Task.sleep(UInt64(delay) * 1_000_000_000)
                let latestData = try await fetchData()

                if latestData != comparisonData {
                    comparisonData = latestData
                    break
                }
            }
        }

        if comparisonData == nil {
            return nil
        } else {
            return comparisonData
        }
    }

    private func fetchData() async throws -> Data {
        let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)
        return data
    }

    func makeAsyncIterator() -> URLWatcher {
        self
    }
}


struct User: Identifiable, Decodable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
}



@MainActor
class UserData: ObservableObject {
    
    static let shared = UserData()
    
    @Published public private(set) var users = [User]()
    
    func fetchUsers() async {
        
        let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "items", withExtension: "json")
        let urlWatcher = URLWatcher(url: url!, delay: 3)

        do {
            for try await data in urlWatcher {
                try withAnimation {
                    let data = try JSONDecoder().decode([User].self, from: data)
                    print(data)
                    users = data
                }
            }
        } catch {
            print("error \(error)")
        }
    }
    
    private init() {
        // Begin loading the data
        Task {
            await fetchUsers()
        }
    }
    
}

struct TestAsync: View {
    
    let data = UserData.shared
    
    var body: some View {
        List(data.users) { user in
            Text(user.name)
        }
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
struct TestAsync: View {
    @StateObject var data = UserData.shared  // <-- or @ObservedObject
    
    var body: some View {
        List(data.users) { user in
            Text(user.name)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So simple, so stupid! Thanks! When you are too deep inside the white rabbit hole this is what happens!